# How to launch process through SSM command as a non-background process?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server

I want to launch Google Chrome (chrome.exe) on my AWS EC2 server using the SSM Api for launching Powershell commands.

I run the powershell command through the C# SSM API:

```
AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient ssmClient = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region));

var ssmDocument = "AWS-RunPowerShellScript";

string command = @"Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'";
var request = new SendCommandRequest()
{
    InstanceIds = new List<string> { instanceId },
    DocumentName = ssmDocument,
    Parameters = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
    {
        { "commands", new List<string> { command } }
    },
};
var response = await ssmClient.SendCommandAsync(request);
```

While it does launch Google Chrome the issue is that the process runs as a background process. Hence, if I RDP to the server, I won't be able to view it.

If I run the Powershell command directly through the server via an RDP connection then Chrome gets launched fully visible.

I need to be able to view the browser window, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

SSM runs in a background *Session*. If you had multiple RDP sessions, then how would you choose which one to start chrome in? If there is no active RDP session, then should it fail?

SSM also runs as a specific user by default: `ssm-user`. Only SYSTEM can start processes in another session, so SSM won't have permission anyways.

---

You can [work around](https://serverfault.com/questions/690852/use-powershell-to-start-a-gui-program-on-a-remote-machine) these limitations with other tools like PSExec or a [scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37536306/7411885), but SSM is not ideal for this.